# Gradle Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: gradle, slf4j, lombok

I am getting compile error. I am not sure which dependency provides this error.
I am using @slf4j lombok annotation to implement logging in my classes.

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/andrius/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/110cefe2df103412849d72ef7a67e4e91e4266b4/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/andrius/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

I am not quite sure in which module and what should I exclude to avoid this.

My setup of Gradle dependencies below.

```
dependencies {
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter') {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
}
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')
testCompileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')
annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.4.0')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2')
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude(module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging')
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out which library (besides spring-boot-starter) was pulling in logback?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to check:

I have found that gradle can be sticky with its cache, so when I get persistent problems like this, I like to `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches` - obviously be careful here and don't wipe out more than you intend.

Run `gradle dependencies` to find out where your logging implementations are coming from. You'll generally find that there'll be a library somewhere that's pulling in `slf4j-log4j12` and another that's pulling in `logback-classic`. You appear to have excluded the `ch.qos.logback` group from where its being pulled in by the `spring-boot-starter`, so I'm guessing that you want that implementation excluded. Therefore, you want to find out where else `ch.qos.logback` is being pulled in and exclude it there as well.

Its a laborious process, and I feel that Spring is being a bit over opinionated by choosing logback-classic, but that's the way it is for the moment.

Not quite an answer, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. `gradle dependencies` allowed me to find the culprit.